# Show that $ | z_{k}|$ is increasing($z_k$ is the zero of partial sum $P_{k}$ of $e^z$ with maximal absolute value)

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

> Show that $| z_{k}|$  is increasing when $z_k$ is the zero of partial sum $P_{k}$
>   of $e^z$ with maximal absolute value.

This is the statement I'm having trouble proving. Can someone help me out here? I've tried applying Liouville Theorem but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P_k'(z)=P_{k-1}(z)$ so the zeroes of $P_k(z)$ are critical points of $P_{k+1}(z)$ and we can assume $k \ge 1$ as $P_0$ has no zeroes. Also notice that $P_k$ has only simple zeroes since $P_{k+1}(z)-P_k(z)=\frac{z^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$ so the only possible multiple zero would be $0$ and that doesn't work.

Gauss Lucas Theorem implies that the zeroes of $P_k$ are strictly inside the convex hull of the zeroes of $P_{k+1}$ so they are of the form $\sum_{m=1}^{k+1} a_mz_m, a_m > 0 \sum {a_m}=1$ where $z_m$ are the zeroes of $P_{k+1}, m=1..k+1$.

This trivially implies that all the zeroes of $P_k$ are strictly less in absolute value than the largest absolute value zero of $P_{k+1}$ by the triangle inequality and the fact that $a_m >0, k+1 \ge 2$ so there are at least two distinct roots of $P_{k+1}$

Proof of Gauss Lucas for polynomials with simple roots - for non-simple roots theorem follows as here if $\zeta$ critical point is not a root, while it is obvious for critical points that are also roots - so double or higher such -

For any $P$ of degree $n \ge 2$ with simple roots $z_1,..z_n$, and $\zeta$ a critical point we have:

$0=\frac{P'}{P}(\zeta)=\sum \frac{1}{\zeta-z_m}=\sum \frac{1}{\bar \zeta-\bar z_m}$, hence

$\sum \frac{\zeta-z_m}{|\zeta-z_m|^2}=0$ which leads immediately to Gauss Lucas by separating the $\zeta$ term and dividing by $\sum \frac{1}{|\zeta-z_m|^2}$

Comment: I don't exactly get it "strictly inside". Do you mean being not on the boundary by that? If so, how can you deduce from Gauss-Lucas theorem that zeroes of $P_k$ don't exist on the border of the convex hull of zeroes of $P_{k+1}$ since gauss-lucas theorem seems not guaranteeing that. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem), theorem says that "If P is a (nonconstant) polynomial with complex coefficients, all zeros of P′ belong to the convex hull of the set of zeros of P".

Comment: $P_k$ has simple zeroes here - critical points can be on the boundary only if they are zeroes of the polynomial also so double or higher zeroes and that doesn't happen here -  all the coefficients in the convex sum are strictly positive when the roots are simple - see the proof of Gauss Lucas I included at the end in the last praragraph